# Return number of items in a table with post id

Tags: sql, id, table

I am trying to return the number of reviews for a given page ID,  I have this so far:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$countreviews = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->wpcreviews     WHERE page_id = ID"));
echo 'Number Of Reviews ' . $countreviews . '';
?>
```

Its not working and I assume it's the end part `page_id = ID`

How do I change the ending to that it searches the `wpcreviews` table for items with the current page ID, which is the same as my post ID?

Answer (score 2):

```
$countreviews = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wpcreviews WHERE page_id = %d', get_the_ID() ) );
```

Comment: Will this work outside of the loop as well? Perhaps get_queried_object_id() might be better.

Comment: it'll work on a single post/page, it pulls from the global $post, which is populated with the first query result before calling the_post().